# Get keys (SINGLE Key of Multiple Arrays Inside an Array) of a Multidimensional Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Could someone help me with my problem?

I want to var_dump specific keys in an multidimensional array. Array_keys, i couldn't figure out how to var_dump just specific or a specific key(s) in a multidimensional array.

Example:

```
$array = array (
  0 => 
    array (
      'id' => '9',
      'gallery_id' => '2',
      'picture' => '56475832.jpg'
    ),
  1 => 
    array (
      'id' => '8',
      'gallery_id' => '2',
      'picture' => '20083622.jpg'
    ),
  2 => 
    array (
      'id' => '7',
      'gallery_id' => '2',
      'picture' => '89001465.jpg'
    ),
  3 => 
    array (
      'id' => '6',
      'gallery_id' => '2',
      'picture' => '47360232.jpg'
    ),
  4 => 
    array (
      'id' => '5',
      'gallery_id' => '2',
      'picture' => '4876713.jpg'
    ),
  5 => 
    array (
      'id' => '4',
      'gallery_id' => '2',
      'picture' => '5447392.jpg'
    ),
  6 => 
    array (
      'id' => '3',
      'gallery_id' => '2',
      'picture' => '95117187.jpg'
    )
);
```

What if i want only to acces the specific keys "id" of the multidimensional array?

Does array_keys work then?

And what else could do the job? Because i am getting stuck now.

Comment: You didn't explained what's your target. "`var_dump` specific keys" doesn't make any sense. What's the problem with accessing IDs like `$array[$i]['id']`?

Comment: There's no *syntactic sugar* to filter by *inner values*. So if you want to `var_dump` only a subset of the array (based on those inner values), you'll actually need to create this subset first. For this there's a multitude of options. [`array_filter`](https://php.net/manual/function.array-filter.php) would be one. Note: [`array_keys`](https://php.net/manual/function.array-keys.php) does not what you think it does.

Comment: @dragoste .., I want to return specific keys in a md-array.

Comment: Did you find your answer? if yes please let us know if any of our answer helped you out and if you still have issues

Comment: `array_column($array,'id')`;

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
array_column();
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-column.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use an [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop to acces the id. like this:

```
foreach($array as $key => $arrays){

 echo $array[$key]['id'];
 echo '<br />';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I wrote simple function that gets array of values by given index name:

```
<?php
$array = array (
  0 => 
    array (
      'id' => '9',
      'gallery_id' => '2',
      'picture' => '56475832.jpg'
    ),
  1 => 
    array (
      'id' => '8',
      'gallery_id' => '2',
      'picture' => '20083622.jpg'
    ),
  2 => 
    array (
      'id' => '7',
      'gallery_id' => '2',
      'picture' => '89001465.jpg'
    ),
  3 => 
    array (
      'id' => '6',
      'gallery_id' => '2',
      'picture' => '47360232.jpg'
    ),
  4 => 
    array (
      'id' => '5',
      'gallery_id' => '2',
      'picture' => '4876713.jpg'
    ),
  5 => 
    array (
      'id' => '4',
      'gallery_id' => '2',
      'picture' => '5447392.jpg'
    ),
  6 => 
    array (
      'id' => '3',
      'gallery_id' => '2',
      'picture' => '95117187.jpg'
    )
);

function dumpValuesByIndexName($array, $indexName)
{
    $tempArray = array();

    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if(isset($value[$indexName]))
            $tempArray[$key] = $value[$indexName];
    }

    return $tempArray;
}

$result = dumpValuesByIndexName($array, 'id');

var_dump($result);
```

And result is:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "9"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "8"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "7"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "6"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

Here is working example: [CLICK!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ef21bde0b9270c6591cc3fc976bfc3d14c53de8a)